# Reduce the size of an image in java

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I want to make sure that an image in my application is not more than 200x200 px and the image size is not more than 150 kB. For example, if the file size of image is more than 150 kB i need to make it 150 kB. The image can be of type jpeg,png etc.

I have the following code for resizing an image to a given width and height

```
private BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());
        Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g.dispose();
        return dimg;
    }
```

But im not sure how to go about reducing the file size to 150 kB. How to do that in java ?.Some example would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to reduce the size of a rendered image (as you state in the title of this question, and if so, what's wrong with the code that  you have), or the size of a file (as you state on one of your last lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an option - [image magic](http://www.imagemagick.org)  - it also has some convenience wrappers for Java, so you can easily use it.

Answer (score 1):

Does your question have any practical relevance or is it just theoretical?

A 200x200 pixel image with a colour depth of 24 bit will uncompressed require 117kB. If you use any reasonable JPEG encoder, it will also never exceed 150kB for such an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can only rezise the image multiple times, to get below the determined file size.